# In the Linux how to use one driver in another driver

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, gpio, spi, led

I have a situation where I have led-gpio driver, which drives the GPIO line, and fec driver for ethernet.

On ethernet fec probe call, I need to set GPIOs and reset GPIO lines using led-gpios. Is this possible? Has any one came across?

I need a multiple byte read and write to GPIO driver which communicates via SPI, that should sending via fec driver.

Comment: You should’ve registered LED class driver. LED subsystem in the kernel has an API to turn LED on, off, etc. There are plenty examples in the existing drivers in the kernel. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2x00leds.c#L91

Comment: I haven’t got what SPI has to do with all that. Are you talking to GPIO expander via SPI, or you want to have GPIO bit bang SPI protocol, if it is the latter, how you connect your LEDs? In the expander case you need to use corresponding driver, but in DT or ACPI.